# Angular template reference reusable?

Tags: angular

It is possible to make `nzDropDownMenu` template reference reusable?

So:

```html
<th nzCustomFilter>
  Cardiology
  <nz-filter-trigger
    [nzActive]="searchValue.length > 0"
    [nzDropdownMenu]="cardiology"
  >
    <i nz-icon nzType="search"></i>
  </nz-filter-trigger>
</th>
<th nzCustomFilter>
  Dermatology
  <nz-filter-trigger
    [nzActive]="searchValue.length > 0"
    [nzDropdownMenu]="dermatology"
  >
    <i nz-icon nzType="search"></i>
  </nz-filter-trigger>
</th>
```

And more and more.

What I want is to pass maybe in `[nzDropdownMenu]=""` value for respective dropdown

Dropdown template:

```html
<nz-dropdown-menu #andrology="nzDropdownMenu">
  <app-drop-down-num
    *ngIf="userData"
    [isEmployment]="true"
    [fields]="'andrology'"
    [listOfDisplayData]="userData"
    (Reload)="Reload($event)"
    (ParentComponet)="ParentComponent($event)"
  ></app-drop-down-num>
</nz-dropdown-menu>
```

In dropdown template, I want to be able to set `#andrology="nzDropdownMenu"` and `[fields]="'andrology'"`

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is `ngTemplateOutlet` is it not?

Comment: i took a look at it but looks like the same what i have today or i do not understand it..;/